# Setting up more than one MQTT broker with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt

Using Docker, I was able to use `eclipse-mosquitto` to set up an MQTT broker with my app, which subscribes to messages. I'm learning Docker right now, so wanted to try adding two brokers to Docker-compose with different ports mapped like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    ...
    links:
      - mqtt
      - mqtt2
    depends_on:
      - mqtt
      - mqtt2
  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    container_name: mqtt-iot
    ports:
      - 1883:1883

  mqtt2:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    container_name: mqtt2-iot
    ports:
      - 1884:1883
```

From **outside of the `myapp` container** (i.e. from my OS X terminal), both `mqtt` and `mqtt2` are working; I can publish and subscribe to messages as expected.

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt', {port: 1883}) // Success
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt2', {port: 1884}) // Success
```

However, when I'm inside the container of `myapp`, I can only connect to `mqtt`. `mqtt2` connection fires the `offline` event right away, and no connection fails. What do I need to do to for `myapp` to be using both of those brokers properly?

Comment: Show more of your myapp code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here

```
links:
  - mqtt
  - mqtt2
```

Links is deprecated now and is not even required in your compose. Next when you use below

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt', {port: 1883}) // Success
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt2', {port: 1884}) // Success
```

From outside. This is based on the ports on the host. When you do it from app container you should do it like below

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt', {port: 1883}) // Success
mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt2', {port: 1883}) // Success
```

The container cannot see mapped port on host. It will see what is inside the network. And in local network both are listen on `1883`

Comment: Is there no longer any use for `links` now?

Comment: Yes, not needed any more